# Derivative of $f(X)=X^T$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is a vector in $R^n$ and $f$ is a function that receives $X$ and gives $X^T$ which is the transpose. Is $f$ differentiable? If yes, what is its derivative?

Comment: I think it is differentiable; its derivative is the function itself. This is because, for $n=2$, you are describing function $f$ as row vector $[x,y]$ goes to column vector $[x,y]^t$. This is "like" identity function; in domain $R^n$ is row space, while co-domain of $f$ is same $R^n$ but looked as column space.

Comment: @pGroups: Yes. I am thinking exactly the same. But I don't know how to prove this. Let's say we are using Frechet's derivative. More generally, what is the derivative of transposing in a Banach space?

Comment: See equation 44 http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. Prove that $f$ is a *linear* operator from $U=\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ to $V=\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$.
2. Prove that $f$ is a *continuous* linear operator from $U$ to $V$.
3. What is the Fréchet derivative of a continuous linear operator?